# Not able to install moment in nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, momentjs, node-modules

I am trying to install moment in node js.But getting the below error :--

> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'moment'.
>
> import * as moment from 'moment';

Below is my tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "build",
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "types": [
      "node",
      "jest"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./src/public/"
  ]
}
```

Below is the command I have executed so far --

```
npm install moment

npm install --save -dev @types/moment
```

Please let me know if I need to add some more information

Comment: Shouldn't be a space between `--save` and `-dev`

Comment: I tried with npm install --save-dev @types/moment also.No luck